Investment strategy to maxmize median wealth
I came across this during an interview prep: Investment in an asset returns $x$ with a probability of $p$ and $-y$ with a probability $q=1-p$. What fraction of my portfolio should be allocated to this investment to maximize median wealth? Let's take $x = 0.4$ and $y = -0.3$. Also, consider two cases a) interest rate = $0$ and b) interest rate = $0.05$.
My initial approach is to use Kelly formula: $f=\frac{p.b-q}{b}$ but not sure what to use for $b=1.4/0.7=2$? Also, I am not sure how to approach median vs. mean? Lastly, I do not know how to account for interest rate. Would appreciate your thoughts. Thanks.

My thoughts: (1) The Kelly formula you give is for the case where yout get b when you win and -1 when you lose. When you win x and lose -y the formula is slightly different, but easy to find. (2) Possibly they are assuming that what you do not invest in this asset will be invested at the risk free rate $r$ (3) I am puzzled by the reference to "median wealth", isn't Kelly about long term expected growth?

Thanks for your thoughts. (1) How about this: $f=\frac{p-q}{a-b}$, where in this case $a=1.4$ and $b=0.7$? Regarding (3), that was my impression as well. I have no ideas how to deal with (2).

I trust this source https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelly_criterion#Investment_formula (I dont have access to my own reference notebook right now). For earning the risk free rate on the uninvested balance, I think there is a slight extension of Kelly to handle it.
